# Android cannot find BindingConversion in include tag

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-databinding

I have made a BindingConversion from boolean to visibility, however Android can't find it, but only when I use it in an include tag. It works at other elements like FrameLyout.

In my abstract ViewModel:

```
@BindingConversion
public static int convertBooleanToVisibility(boolean visible) {
    return visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}
```

Then in my xml (TestViewModel inherits from ViewModel):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="oliveradam.testapp.viewmodels.TestViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:theme="@style/toolbarStyleMusicView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <include
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.isVisible}"
            layout="@layout/layout_test"
            app:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Error:(139, 29) error: cannot find symbol method setVisibility(boolean)

I'm working on Android Studio 2.2 RC.

Comment: If you hardcode the visibility, rather than using data binding, does it work? `<include>` [is not documented to support arbitrary attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include).

Comment: No, Error:(142, 30) error: cannot find symbol method setVisibility(int)

Comment: Then presumably `android:visibility` is not available for `<include>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this is not working, but I think its the layout tag in include. You can't use these tags for databinding. So I deleted the includes, used a viewstub and changed the layouts programmatically.